# Is there any site to get good and free font families?

Tags: fonts, xetex

Since I started to use XeTeX, I found out that having many font families installed is very useful when we want to change the look of the document?

Does anybody know a place to get good fonts (if possible, families)?

Comment: Not sure this is really an appropriate question for the site, given that it's not really related to LaTeX specifically.

Comment: This isn't relatex to LaTeX. Is related to XeTeX. And XeTeX is contamplated by "Friends" in the title of the page.

Answer (score 13):

If you're looking for free license fonts, try [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/).

You have to be somewhat careful looking for fonts online, since some of the so-called "free font" pages online are distributing fonts illegally. FontSquirrel at least provides info on the license.

Comment: Great site. Are there similar ones?

Answer (score 9):

Wikipedia has lists of [Open source typefaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aOpen_source_typefaces) and [Free software Unicode typefaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aFree_software_Unicode_typefaces). In particular, anything based on the [fonts freed by URW++](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/trunk/ghostpdl/urwfonts/) usually looks decent.

Answer (score 2):

SIL International maintain a [list of free fonts](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL_fonts) covered by the Open Font License. As examples, Inconsolata, Linux Libertine, Andika, Gentium and STIX.

Not updated for a few years, the [Unicode Font Guide For Free/Libre Open Source Operating Systems](http://unifont.org/fontguide/) still has some useful information.

The Gnu [freefont](http://www.gnu.org/s/freefont/) was designed with "desktop publishing" in mind but also, to quote from their own write up, they "are especially pleased with the Mathematical Operators range, with which most of the glyphs used in LaTeX can be displayed."

Finally the [TUG fonts page](http://www.tug.org/fonts/) includes many free fonts with details of licenses.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a LaTeX font related site. Not sure if it is related to xetex or not?

- [Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html)