# Cannot find warnock.sty aller.sty and luximono.sty

Tags: fonts, texlive

When running the brochure [template from here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latex-brochure). Got the error warnock.sty aller.sty and luximono.sty not found. I am using TeXLive 2011 in Debian GNU/Linux

Comment: My Guess: These are fonts which are missing, need install by purchasing for price or free. see [Is there any site to get good and free font families?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5188/15717)

Comment: For Luximono see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22157/how-to-use-the-luximono-font-with-tex-live

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is neither `warnock.sty` nor `aller.sty` on CTAN, therefore also not in TeX Live.

For `luximono` one can get through with [`getnonfreefonts`](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/), but on a Debian provided TeX Live this is going to be problematic. By the way, TeX Live 2011 is really old. It's better if you try installing a “vanilla” TeX Live 2013 (see http://tug.org/texlive for instructions).